# srml_system::Trait::Hash equality comparison

Tags: rust, substrate

How can I perform an equality comparison on substrate Hash trait?

Say I have the following code, with `owned_vec` contains a vector of `Hash`:

```rust
use support::{decl_module, decl_storage, decl_event, dispatch::Result,
  StorageValue, StorageMap, ensure, traits::Currency };
use system::ensure_signed;

// this is needed when you want to use Vec and Box
use rstd::prelude::*;
use runtime_primitives::traits::{ As, Hash };
use parity_codec::{ Encode, Decode };

// Our own Cat struct
#[derive(Encode, Decode, Default, Clone, PartialEq, Debug)]
pub struct Kitty<Hash, Balance> {
  id: Hash,
  name: Option<Vec<u8>>,
  base_price: Balance, // when 0, it is not for sale
}

// This module's storage items.
decl_storage! {
  trait Store for Module<T: Trait> as CatAuction {
    Kitties get(kitties): map T::Hash => Kitty<T::Hash, T::Balance>;
    KittyOwner get(owner_of): map T::Hash => Option<T::AccountId>;
    OwnedKitties get(kitties_owned): map T::AccountId => Vec<T::Hash> = Vec::new();
  }
}

decl_module! {
  pub struct Module<T: Trait> for enum Call where origin: T::Origin {
    fn deposit_event<T>() = default;

    pub fn transaction(origin, kitty_id: T::Hash) -> Result {
      let sender = ensure_signed(origin)?;
      let kitty_owner = Self::owner_of(kitty_id).ok_or("Kitty has no owner.")?;
      let mut kitty = Self::kitties(kitty_id);

      <OwnedKitties<T>>::mutate(kitty_owner, |owned_vec| {
        let kitty_index = 0;

        for (i, el) in owned_vec.iter().enumerate() {
          // This is where the compilation error occurs!
          if el != kitty.id { continue }
          kitty_index = i;
        }
        owned_vec.remove(kitty_index);
      });

    }    
  }
}
```

It gives me compiler error that:

```
no implementation for `&<T as srml_system::Trait>::Hash == <T as srml_system::Trait>::Hash

help: the trait `core::cmp::PartialEq<<T as srml_system::Trait>::Hash>` is not implemented for `&<T as srml_system::Trait>::Hash`
help: consider adding a `where &<T as srml_system::Trait>::Hash: core::cmp::PartialEq<<T as srml_system::Trait>::Hash>` bound
```

Thank you!

p.s: Aware the tutorial says that looping through a vector is not encouraged in runtime module implementation.

Comment: I see that `type Hash: Parameter + Member + MaybeSerializeDebug + MaybeDisplay + SimpleBitOps + Default + Copy + CheckEqual + Hash + AsRef<[u8]> + AsMut<[u8]>` at [here](https://crates.parity.io/srml_system/trait.Trait.html#associatedtype.Hash). There is a MaybeDisplay, which is a Display type. But when trying to use `to_string()`, and put `use std::string::{ ToString };` at the beginning, compiler gives ``error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type or module `std``.

Comment: "help: consider adding a `where &<T as srml_system::Trait>::Hash: core::cmp::PartialEq<<T as srml_system::Trait>::Hash>` bound"

Comment: @Stargateur updated to show the full & relevant code.

Comment: There is a [`CheckEqual` trait](https://crates.parity.io/sr_primitives/traits/trait.CheckEqual.html), have you tried using it?

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi I would expect `fn check_equal(&self, other: &Self)` returns a Bool, but it instead returns nothing. Is there an example how to use that function?

Comment: It seems you are right. In this situation, you can define your own function to compare two Hashes, just copy the `check_equal` function and return the bool you want. In general, it seems that Hashes are not really meant to be used this way, nor would I suggest doing transactions the way you have done above. If you follow the tutorial, we use a little extra storage to keep track of the index of each kitty, and use that as the method to remove it from the list, hence removing iteration.